# Commands on Form Load

Tags: vb.net

I have a command in a form which activates on Form Load which is as follows

```
Private Sub frm_15_IssueWarning_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
lbl_incidentid.Text = frm_6_UpdateIncident.lbl_incidentid.Text
'checks to see if a containment already exists for the Incident, if it does, hide the save containment button
 Dim SqlString As String = "select [containmentid],[incidentid],[containmentdate],[containment] from [containment] WHERE [incidentid] = @incidentid"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@incidentid", lbl_incidentid.Text)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                conn.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    If reader.Read() Then
                        Button1.Visible = False
                    Else
                        Button1.Visible = True
                    End If
                Finally
                    reader.Close()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

And all this works great, however the first command

```
lbl_incidentid.Text = frm_6_UpdateIncident.lbl_incidentid.Text
```

If I remove this line and place it in form 6 so that when pressing the button on form 6 to open form 15 it includes the line

```
lbl_incidentid.Text = frm_15_IssueWarning.lbl_incidentid.Text
```

The rest of the command on form load no longer works, previously this has'nt been a problem because you could only access form 15 from one location but now this is changing so the form can be opened from various locations. Is there a command I can write here so that the form knows what form was open/pressed in order to make it here and act accordingly or can anyone suggest another way round this issue? I apologise if this doesnt make much sense, its a bit of a ramble.

Comment: Controls make for *horrible* variables (if `Id` is a number, you have stored it as Text).  Since a form is a class, you can add an `IncidentId` property and pass the data that way

Comment: That may be so but I know so little about vb its untrue and I am lost when it comes to property's I have tried implementing them previously but I cant get them to work

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed the forms a little, instead of opening the form and closing the previous form straight away I inserted an if statement to see what previous form was open before closing it so the new form could act accordingly, please see example below

```
'checks to see which form is open to see where to get incident if from
    If frm_6_UpdateIncident.Visible = True Then
        Me.lbl_incidentid.Text = frm_6_UpdateIncident.lbl_incidentid.Text
        frm_6_UpdateIncident.close()
    End If
    If frm_17_IncidentView.Visible = True Then
        Me.lbl_incidentid.Text = frm_17_IncidentView.lbl_incidentid.Text
        frm_17_IncidentView.close()
    End If
```

It was actually really simple, no idea why I didint think of this in the first place